# Drawing on JTextPane in concrete place

Tags: java, swing, drawing, jtextpane

Let's say we have a JTextPane and its size is set to A4 paper format size. Orientation of the page is vertical. Let's divide our page into three equal parts. When I write something in one part (in random place) I want that inserted text would be drawn on two remaining parts of the page in such a place that if I fold my page on three, all three texts will be in the same place.
Is ther any way to achieve this?

This should look like this:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNJDl.png]

Comment: you can leverage the fact that the top and bottom should be the same and the middle is a reflection of the bottom/top, I think I would actually reuse the same object for the bottom/top and make my adjustments to the y axis for the middle

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood what you want, so please correct me if I misunderstood. You can save the image of your textPane when displayed, and draw that image reverted or normally as needed. See below:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("test");
                mainFrame.setSize(300, 100);
                mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                //layout to make every part the same size
                Container pane = mainFrame.getContentPane();
                pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));

                //create the elements
                JTextPane source = new Source();
                final JPanel copy = new Copy();
                final JPanel revertedCopy = new RevertedCopy();

                //add the elements
                pane.add(source);
                pane.add(revertedCopy);
                pane.add(copy);

                //This is just to display the splitting lines
                source.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 0, 1, 0, Color.BLACK));

                //this is just to repaint the other panels when image changes
                source.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                        if(evt.getPropertyName().equals("drawing")) {
                            copy.repaint();
                            revertedCopy.repaint();
                        }
                    }
                });

                mainFrame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    static BufferedImage image;
    static class Source extends JTextPane {
        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paint(g);
            //we edit the image each time the textPane is repainted
            image = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
            boolean caretVisible = getCaret().isVisible(), selectionVisible = getCaret().isSelectionVisible();
            if(caretVisible) getCaret().setVisible(false);
            if(selectionVisible) getCaret().setSelectionVisible(false);
            super.paint(image.createGraphics());
            if(caretVisible) getCaret().setVisible(true);
            if(selectionVisible) getCaret().setSelectionVisible(true);

            //we let the copies know about the changes
            firePropertyChange("drawing", null, image);
        }
    }
    static class Copy extends JPanel {
        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paint(g);
            //we just draw the image
            if(image!=null) g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
        }
    }
    static class RevertedCopy extends JPanel {
        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paint(g);
            //we just draw the image reverted
            if(image!=null) g.drawImage(image, 0, image.getHeight(), image.getWidth(), -image.getHeight(), this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1+ I would also add getCaret().setSelectionVisible(false); though

Comment: I hesitated as I have actually no idea what it is meant for ^^. But yes, you're probably right.

Comment: WHen you select text the selection is reflected in the image without switching visibility off

Comment: No, I know. What I mean is that I hesitated to add that line in my original code as I have no idea if he wants the selection to be reflected or not. But you're right, he probably doesn't. I'll edit my code.

Answer (score 0):

A `DocumentListener` is needed . On `changeEvent` the text should be copied (*till the caret position*) and appened adjusting line gaps (for overflow of text). `CaretPosition`should be keep into the original position. What happens when text overflows the first part should be taken care of.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace root view with your own one. View has method

```
public void paint(Graphics g, Shape allocation)
```

You override the method and call `super.paint(g, allocation)` 3 times translating Graphics vertically.

Also you should override `getPreferredSpan()` to triple original vertical span.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. But I have another question. Is there a way to get the position of the inserted string on the text pane?

Comment: Yes. You can use code http://java-sl.com/JEditorPaneStructureTool.html to get view's rectangle if you have offset in the Document